# Purpose of Isolation in Power Supplies

Tags: voltage, current, ac, mains, three-phase

I have a general question.

Suppose, I have a PCB, (an electronic device), which is powered from the Electrical socket (from mains grid). Let us assume it is single phase.

When the mains power supply is given to the PCB, its reference is neutral. Its return path is neutral.

The AC-DC module in the PCB, converts the AC to DC. In this case, what is the DC output referenced to? Is it referenced to neutral.

Can someone help to understand the ground/return current concept when single phase AC needs to be converted to DC and why isolation is required? What happens if no isolation is there?

Please take this [AC-DC module](https://recom-power.com/pdf/Powerline_AC-DC/RAC15-K_480.pdf) as an example? What to connect the output pins of the module?

Answer (score 3):

How the output of a power supply works depends on the power supply.

It can be isolated or non-isolated.

There is no one answer to where the output is referenced.

If the output is not isolated, you can't have user touchable parts that are not isolated.

For example, a mobile phone charger must be isolated or people could get killed if they touch the metallic USB connector and e.g. a grounded device at the same time.

And for example, if you make a hair dryer, it has no user connectable connectors or touchable metal parts and it has an insulating plastic case so it can have a non-isolated supply.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When you say, a mobile charge must be isolated, how would it be actually isolated? Using a transformer, right? But in the power supply ac-dc module shared above, we don't have a transformer right? What should be connected to the +Vout and -Vout pins of the module?

Comment: @Freshman That is an isolated power supply so it probably contains a transformer.  You would connect the positive lead of the load to the positive terminal and the negative to the negative, just as the names imply.

Comment: Isolated power supplies have a transformer. Usually you connect your load to the +Vout and -Vout pins.

Answer (score 3):

The first question is where is the return path when it is isolated. Well, to answer that, you need to think of a transformer. Even if there is no direct current path between the primary and the secondary, there is a magnetic coupling between the two that allows one to transfer power to the other. So the current path is only in your inductance of your secondary. Your primary has its own current path. The coupling allows power to transfer from one to the other.[image: Wikipedia]

The second part is why devices are isolated. Well, that one come to safety. If, for instance, you were to place a half rectifier directly on the main line and then place a buck converter, you would have a DC PSU non-isolated. The DC ground would be the neutral. What happens if, by mistake the polarity of your AC line is inverted and the main is your reference? Well, if you were to touch that and any grounded equipment, you'd get shocked. That's an extreme example, but let's say your computer is neutral referenced and you were to plug another device like a monitor that was also neutral referenced, you essentially are creating another path for AC current to go trough, which is not designed to support those currents! Finally, if there were to be a malfunction in the main grid, this would propagate to your device.
Many more examples can be given!

The third question is where the DC is referenced, well, that one is easy: to nothing! That's the purpose of isolation! In practice, there is some leakage current to some other device so it will often be ground referenced, but, that's not a given.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a small request. 1. Could you please give some images/illustrations to support your answer so that I can understand it better? 2. Could you please tell me what to connect on the two output pins (+Vout & -Vout) on the AC/DC module shared above?

Comment: Sure, you can go on the wikipedia page to understand better how transformer works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer!

Comment: The output of your converter can be used has is. The negative is now your DC reference and the positive is your power, or you could define it has you whish really.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that the vast majority of AC->DC power supplies are isolated, as that is required for safety.

The supplies you linked to are isolated - the table on page 4 says the input/output isolation is good for 3.6 KV.

Whether you leave the DC output floating, connected to AC Neutral, or connected to Earth Ground is up to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain with an image of why the AC/DC power supply should be isolated?. What would happen if the power supply is not isolated, like how would the current flow occur? 2. When the page 4 says of isolation of 3.6kV, what does it effectively mean? That the input and output can have a maximum voltage difference of 3.6kV?

Comment: Think of it like that your device could be referenced at the main voltage. Any signals would be hundreds of volt. You might get away with it (for instance, all the lights in your home are switched at those voltages). But usually, it's not desirable since every signals are very dangerous.

Comment: The isolation means that the voltage between the primary side (main) and the secondary(DC) can't be greater than 3.6kV (or isn't tested for higher then). So, from the ground of your main, you can offset your voltage anywhere up to 3.6kV. In most case, you wouldn't do that, but it can happen. Otherwise, it is mostly a safety number that will be required by electrical regulation.

Answer (score 2):

Lets try to look at the simplest scenario possible by converting mains AC into DC, using a bridge rectifier (the four diodes shown below), without isolation.

The DC negative terminal is sitting at 1/2 the mains voltage in comparison to natural/ground.
This means if the mains voltage is 110V-240V (depending on country) then the negative terminal is 55-120V which can be lethal.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> why isolation is required?

In most mains power systems the neutral is tied to ground somewhere. However.

1. Not all supplies even provide a neutral connection. There are some places where both of the pins on a domestic socket are live in normal operation. In an industrial scenario one sometimes comes across 3-phase no-neutral supplies.
2. Even when there is a neutral not all countries use polarised plugs. German "Schuko" plugs/sockets are unpolarised, as are the non-earthed Europlugs.
3. Even when the plugs are polarised you can't always rely on which way round the sockets will be wired up. In particular this applies to French sockets.
4. Wires can break, plugs and sockets can produce poor contact. If a neutral connectoin breaks then loads will likely pull the neutral wire up to live potential.
5. Parallel paths can be problematic. Either tripping RCDs/GFCIs or causing wires to be overloaded.

Put all these things together and it adds up to one thing. Designers of most electrical equipment* must treat the nominally neutral input connection as hazardous, just like they treat the nominally live input connection as hazardous.

That means an equipment designer typically has two choices.

1. Use an isolated power supply where the isolation meets safety requirements for protecting users from the mains.
2. Use a non-isolated power supply (or an isolated one where the isolation doesn't meet safety requirements) and treat everything connected to the output of that power supply as hazardous.

For simple but high-volume equipment with no communication interfaces, the cost savings of a non-isolated power supply can be worth the extra effort to insulate the parts on the secondary side to mains safety standards.

Most of the time though, the isolated power supply wins out as the easier way to make the overall device safe.

> what is the DC output referenced to?

It isn't strongly referenced to anything.

However there will be some leakage between input and output sides. In the case of your module this is specified as "200uA max".

That is low enough that it should be safe to touch the output. However you may decide to tie the output to mains ground so that the leakage current flows to ground rather than flowing through whatever is touching the output.